# Cannot delete tabs from middle in tab layout (Position unchanged)

Tags: android

I created a dynamic tab layout using the tutorial from

https://github.com/jintoga/Dynamic-Viewpager-Custom-TabLayout

everything goes well and dynamic tab is created based on button clicks.

But i am able to close the table from the last tab. but when i tries to close a tab from somewhere middle it force closes SOMETIMES showing the error:

```
 Process: com.example.dat.testdynamicviewpager, PID: 8156
                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a
```

I uses this ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
        TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFrag(int position) {
        removeTab(position);
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getTabView(final int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        TextView tabItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTabItemName);
        CircleImageView tabItemAvatar =
            (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTabItemAvatar);
        ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRemove);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Remove", "Remove");
                removeFrag(position);
            }
        });

        tabItemName.setText(mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
        tabItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));


                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy);

        return view;
    }

    public void destroyFragmentView(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
    }

    public void removeTab(int position) {
        if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

The error is showing at :

```
 public void removeTab(int position) {
        Log.e("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));
        if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0 && tabLayout!=null) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

what is wrong here?

I found where the issue exists. example After creating 7 tabs (0-6 positions), And when I deleted 0th position tab then the total position remains 6 and unchanged) while if I delete the last tab say 6th position tab, then position changes to 5 (here no issue) ) so what can we do to solve this??

Comment: set the viewpager adapter again after remove the items from the list. hope this will solve your problem

Comment: why notifyDataSetChanged(); is not in the code part of remove tab position is it an editing mistake or what

Comment: your checking child count > 0 with position is available are not, if yes check visibility, it may issue of focus

Comment: @rajahsekar. So what should i do here?

Comment: @Noorul. Can you please paste a sample snippet

Comment: @krishankTripathi `notifyDataSetChanged();` is the removeTab

Comment: @KarthikCP Instead of removing tab from tab layout try to remove fragment from list and refresh view pager. Tab layout is attached to view pager so it may update tab layout, i am not tried but you can check once.

Comment: @rajahsekar. I am removing fragment from the list as you can see in `removeFrag` function

Comment: yes i have seen but your removing tab first where your getting error.

Comment: @rajahsekar. So should remove the fragment first?

Comment: I am not sure but u can check once

Comment: @rajahsekar. i changed the `removeTab(position);` after removing fragment.. `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165536/discussion-between-rajahsekar-and-karthik-cp).